# Cardview irremovable grey underline (Android 4.0.4 devices)

Tags: android, material-design, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-cardview, underline

[image: Cardview grey underline]

In android 4.0.4, my cardviews are appearing with a feint grey underline near the bottom. I can't seem to get rid of it, I tried messing around with margins and padding etc but no luck.

Heres my XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/button_daily_calls"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_menu_button_topmargin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/menu_button_leftmargin"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/menu_button_elevation"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_button_radius"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
        android:text="DAILY CALLS"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_textsize"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.IntelliDroid" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!--<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="hagDividerVertical">@drawable/breadcrumb_themed_divider</item>
    <item name="hagSelectableItemBackground">@drawable/breadcrumb_themed_item_background</item>-->
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/appbar_elevation</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="menu_labels_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBarAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">
        @drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light
    </item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogText">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogText.Bold" parent="DialogText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogText.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertText">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_xlarge</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/unavailable</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderListRowLarge" parent="TextHeaderListRow">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderListRow">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeader">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeader_Secondary">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_xlarge</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderBold">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderBoldXLarge">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_xlarge</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderBoldCentered" parent="TextHeaderBold">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderLightCentered">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_2</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="TextHeaderLight">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_2</item>
</style>

<style name="TextBody">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="PushButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
</style>

<style name="SalesHistoryValue" parent="TextHeaderBold">
    <item name="android:width">125dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemContent">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemTextHeaderNoPadding">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemTextHeader" parent="ListItemTextHeaderNoPadding">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemTextHeaderSub" parent="ListItemTextHeader">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_2</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemTextBodyHeader">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_1</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemTextBody" parent="ListItemTextBodyHeader">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_2</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemImage">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/tab_side_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/tab_side_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/tab_side_padding</item>
</style>

<style name="TreeViewListStyle" parent="@android:attr/listViewStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
</style>

<style name="UnreadCount">
    <item name="android:textSize">18.0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/body_text_2</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/tab_side_padding_large</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemContainerBase">
    <item name="android:minHeight">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight</item>
</style>

<!-- a simple list item is one whose container and content are the same view -->
<style name="SimpleListItem" parent="style/ListItemContainerBase">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>

<!-- used for more complex list items, e.g. those with stars aligned to the top-right -->

<style name="ListItemContainer" parent="style/ListItemContainerBase">
    <item name="android:background">@color/abs__holo_blue_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ScannerStep">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="HistoryRow" parent="style/ListItemContainerBase">
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_bottom_border</item>
</style>

<style name="ChartLabel">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent_1</item>
</style>

<style name="BorderedLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/layout_bordered_background</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/tab_side_padding_medium</item>
</style>
```

Dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
<dimen name="appbar_dashboard_height">112dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appbar_elevation">6dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_width">300dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_height">104dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_elevation">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_image_elevation">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_radius">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_padding">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_textsize">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="top_menu_button_topmargin">128dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_leftmargin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_button_topmargin">4dp</dimen>

<dimen name="twitter_container_width">600dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_container_height">275dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_container_radius">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_container_left_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_container_right_margin">16dp</dimen>
<!--<dimen name="twitter_container_top_margin">88dp</dimen>-->
<dimen name="twitter_container_top_margin">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_container_bottom_margin">-16dp</dimen>

<dimen name="sync_status_container_left_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="sync_status_container_top_margin">110dp</dimen>

<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_width">230dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_height">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_radius">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_margin_top">12dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_top_margin_top">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dashboard_option_button_left_margin">0dp</dimen>

<dimen name="dunno_container_width">200dp</dimen>

<dimen name="reconciler_container_height">248dp</dimen>

<dimen name="font_size_for_pod_row">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="vertical_padding_for_pod_row">6pt</dimen>
<dimen name="font_size_for_show_row">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_size_for_pod_details">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="vertical_padding_for_show_row">3pt</dimen>
<dimen name="standard_dialog_width">340dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_height">38dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_small">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_medium">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_mediumlarge">12dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_large">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_xlarge">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_xxlarge">32dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_xxxlarge">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_dashboard">52dp</dimen>
<dimen name="tab_side_padding_dashboard_top">85dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_image_padding_large">168dp</dimen>
<dimen name="actionbar_compat_height">45dp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_small">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_medium">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_large">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_xlarge">32sp</dimen>
<dimen name="drawer_height">42dp</dimen>
<dimen name="signature_capture_width">520dp</dimen>
<dimen name="previous_comments_popup_width">520dp</dimen>
<dimen name="social_image_maxwidth">112px</dimen>
<dimen name="social_image_maxheight">112px</dimen>
<dimen name="twitter_content_height">85dp</dimen>
<dimen name="list_row_order_height">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="list_row_sales_item_width">68dp</dimen>
<dimen name="survey_question_width">320dp</dimen>
<dimen name="survey_question_width_text">640dp</dimen>
<dimen name="popup_maps_width">480dp</dimen>
<dimen name="popup_maps_streetview_width">240dp</dimen>
<dimen name="popup_maps_streetview_height">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="gallery_image_width">260dp</dimen>
<dimen name="gallery_image_height">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_thumbnail_size">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_thumbnail_spacing">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="list_row_spacing">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="product_image_size">240dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>



<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
```

Comment: remove the `android:elevation="@dimen/menu_button_elevation"`

Comment: just did, still the same result.

Comment: ok . try removing `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` also

Comment: nothing, I actually put this in to try to solve the problem

Comment: Please post your style.xml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try substituting

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

with

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

This should prevent the Corners from overlapping therefore making no gap between the picture and the CardView.

And so it works for all the different Android versions you should do something like:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(true);
    } else {
        cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
    }
```

This should help because there is always a padding around the image when you work with Android 4.0.4. When you set the             `cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);` it should not do that anymore.