# Undesired grey line in Cardview in Android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am using a recycler view in Android with Card Views. Unfortunately there is an undesired grey line between the different cardview items in the Recyclerview as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

I tried to change `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` as recommended here [Cardview irremovable grey underline (Android 4.0.4 devices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678559/cardview-irremovable-grey-underline-android-4-0-4-devices) but it did not solve the problem. I also tried to change `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap` but also this did not change it.

Any idea how I can get rid of this line?

Here is my cardview XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView_itemOrder"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_62sdp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/cardview_foreground_rim"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"


    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/_1sdp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"


    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_orderName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.21"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_orderName"
            android:background="#bcbcbc" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView_Information"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.29"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line1"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_orderInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="142dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp"

                    />


          </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView_Information"
            android:background="#bcbcbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.12"
            android:text="Time\n 22:22"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line2"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Time"
            android:background="#bcbcbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.12"
            android:text="Table\n 10"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line3"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Table"
            android:background="#bcbcbc" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_MessageIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_mail_24" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_CancelIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.84"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_messageIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Send\n message"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_6sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_MessageIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_MessageIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_MessageIcon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_cancelIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_6sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_CancelIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_CancelIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_CancelIcon" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the foreground XML file for the black rim around the cardview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="15dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: try using [material design cardview](https://material.io/components/cards/android) instead of androidx

Comment: The CardView has an implicitly set elevation of 2dp (not sure about the exact value). You need to explicitly set the elevation to 0dp by using cardElevation and elevation attribute of the CardView. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Priyansh for your answer. It worked with your suggested solution. I really appreciate your help.